# GoLang - Is there a way to profile memory usage of code that uses reflect?

Tags: memory, reflection, go, profiling

I am using `gocraft/web` in a project and am trying to debug some high memory usage. `gocraft/web` uses reflection to call handlers. I've set up the `net/http/pprof` profiler which works very well, but the largest block of memory, and the one that I am iterested in, only shows `reflect.Value.call` as the function. That's not very helpful.

How can I get around the fact that `gocraft/web` is using reflection and dig deeper into the memory profile?

Here's an example of the profile output I am seeing:

[image: Example Profile]

Comment: Can you try profiling this with go1.5? A side effect of the new runtime is that it exposes more internals to the profiler.

Comment: @JimB that would have been awesome if it had worked but unfortunately it doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @thwd for filing http://golang.org/issue/11786 about this. This is a display issue in pprof. All the data is there, just being hidden. You can get the data you need by invoking pprof with the `-runtime` flag. It will also show data you don't need, but it should serve as a decent workaround until Go 1.6 is out.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you can't directly. `reflect.Value.call` calls `reflect.call` which forwards to `runtime.reflectcall` which is an assembly routine implemented in the runtime, for example for amd64, [here](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/f5d494bbdf945f2662eb4da45cdb75de2b7d43d4/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s#L371). This circumvents what the profiler can see.

Your best bet is to invoke your handlers without reflection and test them like that individually.

Also, enabling the profiler to follow reflective calls would arguably be an acceptable change to propose for the next Go iteration. You should follow the [change proposal process](https://docs.google.com/document/d/12Nj3YuQYFFMkL1Dv39q3JZrDHjtq2lZMRejmfQeBGpU/edit) for this.

Edit: [issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/11786) created.

Comment: @cellofellow: if you're not planning to propose the change please tell me so I can do it.

Comment: go ahead and make the proposal :)